# Can I export my hands from Sharkscope HUD to poker tracker 4, DriveHUD, etc?

Tags: cash-game, hand-history, software, hud, cash

I'm using Shark scope HUD for tournaments and have about 55k tournament hands and 4k ring game hands. I am switching from focusing on tournaments to ring games, so I have decided to use Poker Tracker 4 instead, because Shark scope is tournament-centric and the actual S.S. database stats are only useful for tournaments. My question is whether or not I use my data from the S.S. HUD into a new PT4 account by exporting my hands from program to program?
Do I need to track all new hands any time I switch programs?

Comment: I would suggest you contact the software vendor. they may have a conversion script available, or if you have some programming knowledge attempt to con vert the files yourself. If they are text files it is a relatively simple task to do. although may take some time on your part, you may still get an answer here, but we are experts in poker,not so much tech support for poker programs and such.